# Proper way to use esc_html__ and esc_attr__ etc for escaping value for translation

Tags: translation, escaping

From the articles on Codex, esc_attr_e is proper way to escaping value for translation. But from other articles, I read about sanitizing issue and security issue for some escaping code.
For my code, I am using this:

```
 <h4><?php esc_attr_e( 'PREVIOUS ARTICLE', 'myweb' ); ?></h4>
```

Is my code proper for translation? If no, what the code should I use for?

Really appreciate for any help

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should use `esc_html_e()` instead of `esc_attr_e()` if you intend to escape your translation.

What is proper depends on your intend

Escaping attributes are well, for escaping attributes inside html tags like inline styles, datas, etc.